# Are any Vishnu Purana commentaries available?

Tags: vishnu-purana

I like to read Vishnu Purana. I found an English translation online. Is there any commentary available for it either online or offline in English/Hindi?

Comment: Related: [Answer1](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/23259/277) and [Answer2](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/23243/277) said that unfortunately no commentary on Vishnu Purana is translated into English.

Comment: @Pandya are they available offline atleast?

Comment: Don't know. Hope others will reply

Comment: @YDS I included offline and Hindi. So not duplicate

Comment: @krr Seems not available in any language other than sanskrit.